# ASP redirect URL

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, url-routing

I want to create redirection rules in .asp files.

For e.g. when I type `www.example.com/states/ABC/XYZ`

It should run `www.example.com/states?state=ABC&city=XYZ` page and browser address should display `www.example.com/states/ABC/XYZ`.

I know how to use .htaccess file in ColdFusion, but no idea how redirect thing works in classic ASP.

Comment: 1) What web server do you have? 2) How much control do you have over it (i.e. can you install extra software on server)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use server.transfer.  It keeps the url the same (there is no actual browser redirect, it's all server-side)

hmm... on second thought, I sort of remember you not being able to use parameters in classic ASP when using server.transfer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now if I want to run " site.com/category.asp?Cat=991″ , which is a asp script that dynamically renders different product category pages depending on the value of the “Cat” parameter value, I will type “site.com/Cat/Bathroom-Faucets/991″ in the browser. This is easy if we have htaccess file. But how I can achieve it in ASP

Comment: it's been a while since I messed with these things, but from memory, you would need to set it up in IIS. Like, create a virtual directory called 'Cat' and a virtual directory inside it 'Bathroom-Faucets', with a document of, say, 'default.asp'. In default.asp you would then get the last part of the url (the 991) and do the server.transfer.   The problem, like I said, is that I think you can't use ?Cat=991 in the server.transfer, so you would probably need to set a cookie or server variable. Another option is look for a IIS plugin that lets you do those redirects like in htaccess

Comment: Do you know similar to server.transfer in Jquery or Javascript ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server version you are using.  If you are on IIS7 or above, you can use the [URL rewriting module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) (you may have to install it with [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)).

If you are on IIS6 or below, you will need a 3rd party tool.  I can recommend [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) personally, [v3 even supports `.htaccess` syntax](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/compatibility.htm).  V2 has a free version which is a single config for the whole server, and the paid for versions are good value.

Comment: I have a shared hosting account and don't have access to IIS server, so can not use ISAPI_Rewrite